# Kotlin + Dagger 2 "lateinit property databaseService has not been initialized"

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

My code builds successfully but gives Exception whenever I run it. Not getting why **Dagger 2** is not initializing the variable. Please tell me where I'm wrong. Giving the Following Exception :

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
> databaseService has not been initialized

Application Class :

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    private val TAG: String = "MyApplication"

    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

    @Inject
    lateinit var databaseService: DatabaseService

    private lateinit var addedPackages: ArrayList<String>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        applicationComponent = buildApplicationComponent()
        applicationComponent.inject(this)

        addedPackages = databaseService.packagesDao().getAllPackages()

    }

    private fun buildApplicationComponent() =
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .build()
}
```

**Application Component:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

    fun databaseService(): DatabaseService

    fun compositeDisposable(): CompositeDisposable

}
```

**Application Module:**

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val application: Application) {

    @ApplicationContext
    @Provides
    fun provideContext() = application

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabaseService() = Room.databaseBuilder(application, DatabaseService::class.java, "VersionChecker").build()

    @Provides
    fun provideCompositeDisposable() = CompositeDisposable()


}
```

**Dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'

    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'

    //Dagger2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'

}
```

Comment: You should initialize it in onCreate

Comment: using dagger I'm doing it in onCreate() only.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some R&D I found that I just need to change the method parameter in inject method in ApplicationComponent. inject() method takes the instance of class in which object has to be injected and I was passing Application class before.

```
fun inject(application: MyApplication)
```

Answer (score -1):

Initialize databaseService in onCreate or use lazy instead of lateinit.